# Bought speakers (HS-307 USB), driver issue

Tags: hardware-compatibility

I just bought [this](http://www.clasohlson.com/uk/USB-Headset/Pr382941000) headset.

It only states the speakers are compatible with Windows but I have bought devices before that made such statements which then turned out to work fine on Linux.

Is there any way for me to get those speakers to work on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Load the `snd-usb-audio` module. If it follows USB audio standards then ALSA will see it, and it will work.

Comment: I could find this http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/how-to-remove-pulseaudio-use-alsa-ubuntu-linux/  but he says "And if PulseAudio is working just fine for you, then I highly recommend that you stick with it." So I guess I should just count my losses and buy another speaker.

Comment: ... What does that article have to do with USB audio?

Comment: how do I load the snd-usb-audio module?

Comment: With the `modprobe` command, assuming it isn't autoloaded when the device is plugged in.